# Cómo dibujar una piramide apuntando hacia la izquierda Java

Tags: java

Necesito imprimir una piramide de asteriscos apuntando hacia la izquierda de manera que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo he logrado hacer que parezca una triangulo rectángulo :(

Este es mi código:

```
public void piramideIzquierda(int altura){
     for (int i = 0; i < altura; i++) {            
         for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
         }

         System.out.println("\n");
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente agrega un for a la inversa después del primer for

```
    public void piramideIzquierda(int altura){
         for (int i = 0; i < altura; i++) {            
             for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
             }
             System.out.println("\n");
         }
         for (int i = 1; i < altura; i++) {            
             for (int j = 0; j < altura - i; j++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
             }
             System.out.println("\n");
         }

    }
```

Donde la altura en esta caso se ira restando conforme aumente `i` por lo cual irá en descenso

Answer (score 0):

La pirámide que dibujaste está apuntando hacia la derecha, no a la izquierda. Omitiendo eso asumo que el dibujo está bien y que en realidad la quieres apuntando hacia la derecha.

Prueba el siguiente código:

```
public void piramideIzquierda(int altura) {
    for (int i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
        int reps = i < altura / 2 ? i / 2 + 1 : (altura - i - 1) / 2 + 1;
        boolean tab = (altura % 2 != 0 || i < altura / 2) == (i % 2 != 0);

        for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
            System.out.print(tab ? "\t*\t" : "*\t\t");

        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Si quieres una pirámide perfecta, debe tener una altura impar y se verá así (ejemplo con `altura = 7`):

```
*       
    *   
*       *       
    *       *   
*       *       
    *   
*
```

Si pones un número par saldrá así (ejemplo con `altura = 8`):

```
*       
    *   
*       *       
    *       *   
    *       *   
*       *       
    *   
*
```